# How to create multiple arrows around a circle pointing to it in a random way in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, vector, illustration

I would like to achieve something like this image, Multiple arrows around a circle pointing to it in a random way, Of course I need something handy that make it faster instead of creating all these arrows manually:
[image: Multiple arrows around a circle pointing to it in a random way]

Comment: What have you tried? Where is that failing?

Comment: If you are just creating one image, I'm sure it's faster to just draw them manually. You could be done by now. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Draw one vertical arrow. Convert the stroke to path and make an union of the parts. The arrow must be one strokeless closed area.

Fill a rectangular area manually by making duplicates of the arrow. You can scale and rotate a little individual arrows to avoid too clinical appearance

Delete the rectangle, select the arrows and make a combined path. The next steps can accept only a single or a combined path, they cannot be groups.

Copy the combined path to the clipboard.

Draw with the Bezier tool a closed curve or make an ellipse.

Insert Path effect Pattern along Path. Take the pattern from the clipboard:

[image]

See the mode "Repeated and Stretched"

The arrows have now the same stroke as the ellipse had and the interior can look hollow. Insert a good fill and stroke to make the arrows look solid. It can be a good idea to fix the effect before making edits because my Inkscape generated harmful glitches when I tried to edit the arrows generated by the effect. Fix by applying Path > Object to Path and apply Path > Break Apart if you must make individual edits to arrows.

[image]

BTW. As already commented, drawing them manually is not slower if you have only a single drawing not bigger than your example and you can accept a preset arrow style. It's only clicking with the Bezier tool and finally selecting all and applying the arrowhead marker in the stroke style dialog.

Comment: Thank you, This worked for me. But I drew big perfect circle then converting to path and applied "Pattern along path" then resized it to be an ellipse, Because drawing ellipse from the beginning and applying the effect to it, doesn't make the desired shape.